# python: pyqt accept close event in overridden closeEvent if conditions are met without user interaction

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I am trying to prevent the user from exiting my `QDialog` that contains a progress bar and to achieve that I thought of overriding the `Qdialog`'s `closeEvent` and that is where my dilemma starts. I do not know how to pass some sort of confirmation to my overridden `closeEvent` that the very long process in my other thread is finished and can now accept a `closeEvent`.

here's what my what my code structure looks like

```
class TaskThread(QtCore.QThread):         
    taskFinished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()        
    def __init__(self, var1, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.sel_proj = var1

    def run(self):
        #very long process for var1
        self.taskFinished.emit()

class progress_win(QDialog):
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        #if only I can pass a variable here depending on the process
  #like if finished == True:
            #event.accept()
        #else:
            #event.ignore() 


        event.ignore()#for now

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow, TaskThread):
    #my main window, also contains other QDialog

    def progbar(self):
        self.prog_win = progress_win()
        self.prog_win.resize(400, 100)

        self.progressBar = QtGui.QProgressBar(self.prog_win)
        self.progressBar.resize(410, 25)
        self.progressBar.move(15, 40)
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,1)

        self.prog_win.installEventFilter(self)
        self.prog_win.show()

        self.myLongTask = TaskThread(var1 = myDataToBeProcessed)
        self.myLongTask.taskFinished.connect(self.onFinished)

    def onStart(self):
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,0)
        self.myLongTask.start()

    def onFinished(self):
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,1)
        self.processResult = self.myLongTask.processedVar1 #getting my result from the long process
        self.prog_win.close()
```

I would like to close the Qdialog when the process is finished but not when the process is ongoing. Can I pass a variable to my overridden event from `onFinished` function? if not then what would be the best course of action?
The examples I always see is this:

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Close',
        "Are you Sure? \nAll your Inputs will be lost.", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
    if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

which requires user interaction, It would be great if there is a guide or example I could follow on the idea that i want.

Basically I want to ignore the close event of the `progbar QDialog` from the user and let something like a function handle the closing.

Comment: You want the user not to be able to close the dialog while the thread is running, and just after finishing the task, you can close the dialog. or do you want the dialog to be closed as soon as the task is finished automatically? Explain all possible cases and what is the behavior you want for each.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: I confuse your explanation, if concrete please explain the final goal and not the method you are thinking

Comment: you must create a boolean attribute that indicates if the condition you want has been fulfilled. and if it is fulfilled just accept the event if the user wishes or execute the close method.

Comment: That's exactly what I am thinking but unfortunately I do not know how to add an attribute to a QDialog, Do I need a `__init__` for that?

Comment: QDialog is a class similar to the others, so it is best to create it inside the constructot and create a setter method.

Comment: `class progress_win(QDialog): def __init__(self, parent=None): QDialog.__init__(self, parent)`

Comment: @eyllanesc, can you post an answer? that is precisely what I needed, I was missing the `QDialog.__init__(self, parent)` in my last try. I thought it was only for QThread, shame, shame, shame

Comment: You better publish your answer, and accept it. I just said basic things, you have more clear the answer  :P